# How to fetch 10000 record in laravel using chunk method?

Tags: excel, laravel, export

I want to fetch large amount of data and export it .Up to 1000 records it works fine but after that server becomes slow and cannot export the file .It takes time to execute query and export it .

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323659/laravel-collection-with-relations-take-a-lot-of-time/45324021#45324021

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Collection with relations take a lot of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323659/laravel-collection-with-relations-take-a-lot-of-time)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [Package](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) it allows to directly export data using Laravel eloquent Model.

Alternatively you can also chunk method on your eloquent.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve all records and then chunk 1000 records at a time. Divide your code in different functions so it become sorted. Even chunk is doing the same it breaks collection into multiple collection.
ex.    User::chunk(1000, function ($rows) {}